# How can I change the background color of shiny dashboard header?

Tags: r, shiny, background-color, shinydashboard, dashboardheader

I would like to have a thin, empty, dashboard header with white background. The three lines to hide the menu would be black. I managed to adjust the height and width of the header, but not the colors. I can I adjust the header colors without using a theme?

```
dashboardHeader(
      titleWidth = 260, 
      tags$li(class = "dropdown",
              tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 20px}"),
              tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 20px;}"),
              tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 20px; padding-top: 1px !important;}"),
              tags$style(".navbar {min-height:20px !important}")
      )
      )
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198452/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-shiny-dashboard-body/52199018#52199018